# Configure Azure IaaS VM to allow access by IP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, azure-networking

I have an Azure IaaS Windows 2012R2 VM which is hosting a test website. The site is accessible externally by the hostname.

What do I need to do to enable access to that same site by IP address?
When I try to ping the IP address I get the message:

```
Request timed out.
```

When I try to ping the working hostname for the site, I get

```
Pinging myhostname.com [nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

On the VM I tried to enable `File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request ICMPv4 - In)`. I also followed [these steps](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add) to enable `IP and Domain Restrictions`, though I'm not sure that's necessary?
I also tried disabling the windows firewall and this did not seem to do anything. I have re-started the VM.

Comment: Can you tell me if you are using the RM portal (portal.azure.com) or the classic portal (manage.windowsazure.com)? the procedure changes depending which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

Azure's load balancer does not support PING (ICMP), which is why you cannot ping your VM's IP address. You can use tcp-based ping tools to achieve this. *Note: You will be able to ping between VMs internally (via each VM's internal IP address), assuming they're deployed into the same vnet / cloud service.*

You can absolutely access your VM by IP address though.

Answer (score 1):

Azure blocks ICMP by default at the Azure Load Balancer end, and thereby you cannot ping the Azure VMs from outside Azure. The rationale behind this to avoid any targeted Ping/ICMP flood attacks, which are a type of DDoS attacks.

However, you can easily enable ICMP and Ping the Azure VM from outside Azure. 
You need to allow Inbound ICMPv4 in your Win Server Firewall, and then setup an NSG Inbound rule in Azure to accept traffic from "Any" Source, "Any" Destination and "Any" Protocol. Ping will work normally thereafter for reaching Azure VMs from Internet.

I have done this numerous times, for hooking up external Monitoring tools like Nagios to my Win Srv VMs.

If you are using latest Win Srv 2016, you will see in your Win Firewall specifically a disabled rule named Virtual Machine Monitoring (ICMPv4), which you just need to enable then. However, this case also you need to open Inbound on Azure NSG like described above.

And moreover, you can ping the Azure VM both using the IP as well as DNS set.

But do know that following the procedure I have described above, you will leave your VMs vulnerable to the Ping/ICMP flood attacks.

However, Azure Perimeter security will anyways pitch in sooner than later, on detecting any such flood attacks, and will likely take actions like blacklisting the originating IPs (from where Pings are happening), and other such measures. You may also see Azure restricting all/any traffic to your VMs unless the situation is fixed by you (or Azure Support), with even notifications coming from Azure support to help resolve the root Issues.

In a nutshell, do not enable ICMP blindly on your Azure VMs. If you know the source IPs from where the request will come, specify them in the NSGs (which I would do always), and avoid specifying “Any” in the NSG Inbound Source.

HTH…

Comment: yes, you're right, We can ping the Azure VM by disable the rule(ICMPv4) in windows firewall.